# How do i combined Python escape characters with a MatLab command?

Tags: python, matlab

The following command works once i have ssh'd to the computer that i want to be on.

```
cd /Volumes/promiseraid9/workspace/sarah2/Facility/; /Applications/MATLAB_R2017a.app/bin/matlab -r "cd /volumes/promiseraid9/workspace/colleen/NewResiduals/j078_8; try, run('ABOVE2019_TF01_MatLabCommands_Test.m'); end; cd /Volumes/promiseraid9/workspace/sarah2/Facility; resid_process_GPS(in_dir_list,out_dir_list);"
```

However, i want to be able to, from a python script, ssh and use the above command but have it come out exactly as shown above (meaning all of the same 's and "s)

So my issue is dealing with Escape characters...

```
os.system('ssh -t cmbrook3@gs694-vegasx2.gsfc.nasa.gov \'cd /Volumes/promiseraid9/workspace/sarah2/Facility/; /Applications/MATLAB_R2017a.app/bin/matlab -r "cd /volumes/promiseraid9/workspace/colleen/NewResiduals/j078_8; try, run(\'ABOVE2019_TF01_MatLabCommands_Test.m\'); end; cd /Volumes/promiseraid9/workspace/sarah2/Facility; resid_process_GPS(in_dir_list,out_dir_list); end;"\'')
```

The main problem is that MatLab is seeing run(\'ABOVE2019_TF01_MatLabCommands_Test.m\') exactly like that instead of just run('ABOVE2019_TF01_MatLabCommands_Test.m')

So what kind of escape characters can i use in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can put your command into a triple quote like this:

```py
command_to_run = (
        '''ssh -t cmbrook3@gs694-vegasx2.gsfc.nasa.gov'''
        ''' 'cd /Volumes/promiseraid9/workspace/sarah2/Facility/; '''
        '''/Applications/MATLAB_R2017a.app/bin/matlab -r '''
        '''"cd /volumes/promiseraid9/workspace/colleen/NewResiduals/j078_8;'''
        '''try, run ABOVE2019_TF01_MatLabCommands_Test.m; end; '''
        '''cd /Volumes/promiseraid9/workspace/sarah2/Facility;'''
        ''' resid_process_GPS(in_dir_list,out_dir_list);"' '''
    ).strip()# command_to_run is a string
os.system(command_to_run)
```

The triple quote allows you to put quote in your string without escaping them.

**Edit**: edit code with modification suggested by @ColleenB.

**Edit2**: more explanation about the `strip` function, I use it in order to delete the last space. Without it, Python cannot interpret the last three quotes (I also could use triple double quotes instead of simple ones).

The parenthesis allows to split the string on many lines instead of having a very long line.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, however it doesn't appear to be reading the m file.  It errors saying "Undefined function or variable 'in_dir_list'".  This in_dir_list is found inside the m file.  Why isn't it reading it?  If i type these commands straight into the computer without ssh'ing these exact commands work just fine.

Comment: Got it fixed.  I just changed run('ABOVE2019_TF01_MatLabCommands_Test.m') to run ABOVE2019_TF01_MatLabCommands_Test.m